# How do I setup a foreign key relationship based on two columns?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, t-sql

I have the following two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[company]
    (
      [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [CompanyName] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DepartmentName] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [ResidentialSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [ResidentialState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [PostalAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [PostalSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [PostalState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [Phone] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_department] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [DepartmentID] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
```

AND

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[user]
    (
      [UserId] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [CompanyID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [DepartmentID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [EmailAddress] [varchar](150) NOT NULL ,
      [Title] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [FirstName] [varchar](100) NOT NULL ,
      [MiddleName] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [LastName] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [DateOfBirth] [date] NULL ,
      [ResidentialAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [ResidentialSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [ResidentialState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [ResidentialCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [PostalAddress] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [PostalSuburb] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalPostCode] [varchar](20) NULL ,
      [PostalState] [varchar](150) NULL ,
      [PostalCountry] [varchar](100) NULL ,
      [Phone] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [Mobile] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [BrowserDetails] [varchar](500) NULL ,
      [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL ,
      [LastLogin] [datetime] NULL ,
      [Created] [datetime] NULL ,
      [CreatedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      [LastModified] [datetime] NULL ,
      [LastModifiedBy] [varchar](50) NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_users] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [UserId] ASC )
        WITH ( PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
               IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
               ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [PRIMARY]
    )
ON  [PRIMARY]
```

I would like a foreign key on `dbo.user` where a company id and department id identifies the correct row on `dbo.company`. Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, by adding a `UNIQUE` constraint (or a unique index) on the `company` table, using these 2 columns:

```
ALTER TABLE company
  ADD CONSTRAINT CompanyID_DepartmentID_UQ
    UNIQUE (CompanyID, DepartmentID) ;
```

Then you can add the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE [user]
  ADD CONSTRAINT Company_User_FK
    FOREIGN KEY (CompanyID, DepartmentID) 
    REFERENCES company (CompanyID, DepartmentID)  ;
```

Test at [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7e5c2/6)

- Minor comment: Since the table `company` has `DepartmentID` as the primary key, shouldn't it be called `department` table? (How do you call the table where the `CompanyID` is the primary key?)